# mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given instead

Tags: mysql

```
if(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'");
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

I know that this is probably a duplicate from somewhere, but this is driving me insane right now. Please help.

Comment: I hope you are escaping your variables. Note that the `mysql` extension will be deprecated soon, and thus removed in the future. Consider using `mysqli`

Comment: @bear No need to escape variables. PHP distinguishes variables when used in double quotes.

Comment: @P5Coder if a variable contained `'`, the query would fail.

Comment: the query is fine, but something happens when i get towards the end of it and the phpmyadmin starts freaking out giving me several sql errors and i've tried a bunch of different things.

Comment: the thing is, i have several other queries just like this and they work fine

Comment: @SolomonArnett the query is returning false.

Comment: @bear how can a single quote cause any problem when the string is enclosed in duoble quotes?

Comment: @bear i'm pretty new to php and mysql, what should the query return?

Comment: @P5Coder An unescaped `'` will cause MySQL to incorrectly read the query. Consider `SELECT x FROM y WHERE name = 'P5'Coder';`

Comment: @SolomonArnett a MySQL resource type, see the answers below for troubleshooting.

Comment: @bear im using mysql_real_escape_string in the code above it already for all inputs. When I run the query to troublshoot it, it just tells me that COUNT does not exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mysql_query()` function call is failing and returning `FALSE` which is an invalid 1st parameter for `mysql_result()`.

Run the `mysql_query()` separately and call `mysql_error()` to get the error.

The query is failing because `COUNT (...)` should be `COUNT(...)` otherwise it tries to find a column called `count` in the table.

Comment: it's telling me that COUNT does not exists

Comment: Ah you need to take the space out between count and the parentheses!

Comment: No problem.. would suggest taking on board the comments about deprecation of methods from the other users.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is displayed when you have an error in your query which caused it to fail.

Note: This error does not appear if no rows are affected by your query. Only a query with an invalid syntax will generate this error.

**Troubleshooting Steps**

Make sure you have your development server configured to display all errors. You can do this by placing this at the top of your files or in your config file: error_reporting(-1);. If you have any syntax errors this will point them out to you.

Use `mysql_error()`. `mysql_error()` will report any errors MySQL encountered while performing your query.

**Sample usage:**

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (false === $result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Run your query from the MySQL command line or a tool like phpMyAdmin. If you have a syntax error in your query this will tell you what it is.

Make sure your quotes are correct. A missing quote around the query or a value can cause a query to fail.

Make sure you are escaping your values. Quotes in your query can cause a query to fail (and also leave you open to SQL injections). Use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape your input.

Make sure you are not mixing mysqli_* and mysql_* functions. They are not the same thing and cannot be used together. (If you're going to choose one or the other stick with mysqli_*. See below for why.)

**Other tips**

mysql_* functions should not be used for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the deprecation process. Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi. If you can't decide, this article will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is good PDO tutorial.

Comment: it's telling me that COUNT does not exists

Comment: You should add the information ("it's telling me that COUNT does not exists") to your question!

Comment: Remove the space after COUNT. If this helped remember to mark as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query should read

```
SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0
```

Remove the space between `COUNT` and `(`user_id`)`